# Show login screen for humans but allow robots to index

Tags: php, wordpress, robots.txt, pinterest

I am working on a Pinterest clone in WordPress at the moment.

I want to know how Pinterest manages to get their site indexed by search engines when you have to log in to see the pin screens?

So, I need a solution where users have to log in to the site, but search engines can still index everything without logging in. Is this technically cloaking?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a Pinterest sample link that's cataloged by Google? Maybe this Q is more apropriate at [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your script by using a reverse DNS lookup. [Google suggest this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80553) method themselves. With PHP you can do this using [`gethostbyaddr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php).

Comment: This is not a good way to detect if they are a googlebot. It's for *verifying* that they are the googlebot.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to check the user-agent string. The full list is at http://user-agents.org/.

If you try the DNS method suggested by Leonard, you'll find it's *extremely* slow. Some IPs don't even have valid reverse lookups. The page in question recommends a reverse lookup only for *verifying the origin of a request that claims to be googlebot in the user-agent string*. You shouldn't worry about people hacking their browsers (pretending to be the googlebot) until you are popular.

Comment: So you'd be happy with people accessing your site without a login/pass just because it's not popular? And don't be fooled in to thinking people "hacking their browsers" is something that in most cases is a simple browser setting.

Comment: I'm saying the DNS verification is Step 2. Step 1 is to just look at the user-agent header. Even the New York times only implemented Step 1 when they put up their paywall. http://www.techairlines.com/new-york-times-paywall-loopholes/

Comment: I am not too fused about people getting around it, its just to prompt new users to sign up, I am aware of the user agent method, maybe it would be better to do this with a cookie, i.e if they have logged in before set a cookie, if no cookie set show login.

But still I have the issue of search engines, maybe use a session id or cookie? would;d they read it?

Is there a way to detect any search bot without listing all the user agent strings?

Comment: You cannot give bots cookies --there are literally hundreds of servers indexing your site, and they don't co-ordinate that much. There is no perfect way to detect bots, but user agent (with optional reverse IP) is as good as it gets.